# Do database systems contain/store picures, sounds and files, or just a reference of them?

Tags: database, file, storage

The other day I was watching a tutorial video on Youtube about db, and in the introduction it said "db stores files such as pictures, sound files ... ".

As far as I know, database systems only store text. This text could be alphabetical, numerical and other characters, and by using a combination of that, we can create links of the actual files that are stored on the server directory.

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most Relational Databases allow for the storage of binary data in the form of some datatype supporting that. In Oracle, for example, this is the `BLOB` datatype (Binary Large Object).

Whether or not this is a good idea is highly subjective and depends on a case to case basis but it definitely is possible